# inserting timestamps with python cassandra prepared statements

Tags: python, cassandra, timestamp, prepared-statement

Is it possible to insert a timestamp value into a Cassandra keyspace using prepared statements of Python Cassandra driver? When I tried to do that, I got the following error message:

Expected: `<class 'cassandra.cqltypes.DateType'>, Got: <type 'str'>`

I see that this problem had been [discussed](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-85) before. But not sure whether it has been resolved. How to do this? Doing the same using simple statements would be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can insert a timestamp value via prepared statements by binding a **datetime** object. I have tried it with success.

Answer (score 0):

Like Aaron said, you need to use a datetime object.  Given a simple table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow2.timestamps (
    bucket text,
    value timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (bucket, value)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (value DESC)
```

This code will INSERT ten timestamps into the `timestamps` table, given a valid (connected) `session`:

```
preparedInsert = session.prepare(
"""
    INSERT INTO stackoverflow2.timestamps (bucket,value) VALUES (?,?);
"""
)
#end prepare statements

for counter in range(1,10):
    currentTime = datetime.datetime.today()
    bucket = currentTime.strftime("%Y%m")
    session.execute(preparedInsert,[bucket,currentTime])
```

Essentially, the `datetime.datetime.today()` line creates a datetime object with the current time.  The `strftime` creates a string time `bucket` from it, and then the `preparedInsert` puts them both into Cassandra.